# Asp.net Charts Line Style

Tags: asp.net, aspchart

I've been trying this for a while but I can not remove these lines or change their color: [image](http://i.tinyuploads.com/2I6Bpr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after trying many properties:

```
mychart.MajorTickMark.Enabled="false"

mychart.MajorTickMark.LineColor = (whatever)
```

Regards.,

k